# Is my 3D printer totally dead?

Tags: prusa-i3, troubleshooting, geeetech

The last few days my 3D printer has not been working, despite the fact that the LCD Screen has been working perfectly (since the problem the LCD bright potentiometer went very sensitive, so the brightness set to the maximum although before the problem it was perfectly calibrated).

The problem arrived when I was unplugging the fan from the board because it wasn't working while the printer was on, suddenly the LCDs brightness set to the maximum so I turned the printer off as fast as I could. When I turned it on again, I had to recalibrate the LCDs brightness and when I tried to move the steppers the weren't working, some of them made strange noises and didn't move. I have to say that now every time I turn on my printer, an orange LED flashes, but I cannot remember if it was normal or not.

My 3D printer: [Geeetech I3 Pro B 3D Printer DIY Kit - Black US Plug    1](https://www.gearbest.com/3d-printers-3d-printer-kits/pp_375209.html)

The board I'm using: [XCSOURCE® Kit de impresora 3D con RAMPS 1.4 Controlador + Mega 2560 Board + 5pcs A4988 Controlador de motor de pasos con disipador de calor + LCD 12864 Controlador gráfico de visualización inteligente con adaptador para Arduino TE621](https://www.amazon.es/XCSOURCE%C2%AE-Controlador-visualizaci%C3%B3n-inteligente-TE621/dp/B01N66HPLL)

Comment: What indicates the maximum LCD brightness? Well, if the potentiometer (POT) were sensitive is due the POT is defective. if defective POT and the bright LCD changes on FAN unplugged, an orange led; this mean 2 things: Wiring are wrong installed (loose wires) and you have an un normal ESD case. if this is the case you need an other ATMEGA

Answer (score 2):

*I would have posted this as a comment, since it is not a definitive answer to the question, but it was too long for a comment.*

Since you were unplugging the fan when the problem started, I would suggest that it is a wiring problem.

The first place I would look is to check the ground connection between the processor board (probably the ATMEGA Arduino), and the board that carries the stepper motor drivers.  If the ground connection is faulty, the board may still work due to sneak ground paths through signal lines.

A simple way to check is to measure the voltage from the GND pin on the ATMEGA to the ground of the driver board.  That voltage should be very close to 0.0 Volts.  You might also check the resistance (using an ohm meter) with the power turned off.  The resistance should be 0.0 ohms, or if the meter is not perfectly calibrated, it should be the same as you measure with the probes connected together.

If either of these readings isn't zero, search for a broken connection.

One sign that ground may be broken is the LCD brightness control sensitivity.  I don't have the schematic to refer to, but if the ground reference for the pot is broken, the output of the pot will be too high.

Another sign is that the stepper motors still make some sounds when they should move.

If you don't find a problem there, check through the other power and ground connections.  Be sure that all GND lines are well connected, all +5 lines are well connected, and that all +12 lines are well connected.